# Django-Wagtail - How to select the "Choose A Page" panel when adding a model to the content panels?

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm not sure if I'm being really thick here but I am struggling to find this panel in the [list of available panels](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/reference/pages/panels.html). At first I thought it was the `PageChooserPanel` but it isn't. This is what I'm looking for:

[image: Choose A Page Panel]

This panel is available when inserting links into the `RichTextField`. It's perfect for my needs but I can't seem to find it anywhere else.

I'm trying to create a field whereby the editor can select either an existing page or link to an external URL. The URL will then feed into a `ref="{{ page.my_url }}"` in my template.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This chooser isn't available outside of rich text, because page links and external URL links have different representations in the database - external links are plain URL strings, but links to pages are stored as a `ForeignKey` pointing to the relevant page ID. (This ensures that the link won't break if the page's slug changes.) As a result, there's no possible field type that you can define on the model that would handle both kinds of value.

A common workaround for this is to use two optional fields side by side - a PageChooserPanel for entering internal links, and a FieldPanel (with a URLField) for external links - and include some logic on your model to return the URL from whichever one was filled in:

```
class SomePage(Page):
    related_page = models.ForeignKey('wagtailcore.Page', null=True, blank=True, related_name='+', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    related_external_url = models.URLField("External link", blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        PageChooserPanel('related_page'),
        FieldPanel('related_external_url'),
    ]

    def related_url(self):
        if self.related_page:
            return self.related_page.url
        elif self.related_external_url:
            return self.related_external_url
```

Comment: An informative, helpful and complete answer... As usual! Thanks @gasman